# Response is not showing from server side

Tags: reactjs

Here i'm using refs concept, After clicking on submit button every-time its refreshing the page and doesn't show any console logs. `userId ,email,password` is getting the undefined value what is the  issue here

Thanks in advance

```
const emailRef = React.createRef();
const passwordRef = React.createRef();    

  const registerUser = () =>{
  const email = emailRef.current.value;
  const password = passwordRef.current.value;
  
  axios.post('/user/register',{userId,email,password})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("response....",response)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("err response", err)
  })
}


      <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
        <TextField
          ref = {emailRef }
          variant="outlined"
          id="email"
          label="Email Address"
          autoComplete="email"
          autoFocus
        />
        <TextField
          ref = {passwordRef } 
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.submit}
          onClick = { registerUser }
        >
          Sign Up
        </Button>
```

Comment: Your current code isn't complete. Always use connected components for these things. And finally, your AJAX calls fires just before loading the component. Make sure you fire it on submission of the form.

Comment: Any reason for using createRef()..

Comment: Also, @simran, make sure you accept answers for all the previous questions you have asked. **You may not be getting good answers or you might not be able to ask questions in the future.** We are a community and we need to help each other by appreciating our efforts.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman you're right, this will discourage the community to help such askers, personally i have a list of people that don't accept answer or at least don't give a feedback after trying out the answers. I see that an answer like you posted below take a precious time to create it and then you'll not receive any feedback or any appreciation

Comment: Thanks for the support @BoussadjraBrahim.

Comment: You're welcome my bro

Answer (score 1):

**Never use `createRef` without any valid reason for accessing the real DOM.** For example, I have made a similar form like what you have got here:

[image: preview]

I started something like this.

```js
const LoginForm = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="Username"
          className="form-control"
          id="Username"
          placeholder="Username"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          id="Password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Added a state using useState, as it's a functional component:

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  username: "",
  password: ""
});
```

Then to make the connected components, I used this event handler commonly for both:

```js
const handleChange = e => {
  // Here, e is the event.
  // e.target is our element.
  // All we need to do is to update the current state with the values here.
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

And attached the event handler and values to both the inputs this way:

```js
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="Username">Username</label>
  <input
    type="Username"
    className="form-control"
    id="Username"
    placeholder="Username"
    name="username"
    value={values.username}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
  <input
    type="password"
    className="form-control"
    id="Password"
    placeholder="Password"
    name="password"
    value={values.password}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
</div>
```

And finally, during the form submission, I took the content from the `state` or `useState`.

Complete working app:

```js
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const handleChange = e => {
    // Here, e is the event.
    // e.target is our element.
    // All we need to do is to update the current state with the values here.
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(values);
    // You'll get both the username and password.
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="Username"
          className="form-control"
          id="Username"
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          id="Password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And now with the values you have got, please use that to send it to the server using Axios. Again, **don't use `createRef`.**

**Snippet**

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<style>.rate {border: 1px solid #f90; padding: 3px 5px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #fc9; margin: 0 25px 0 5px;}</style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const handleChange = e => {
    // Here, e is the event.
    // e.target is our element.
    // All we need to do is to update the current state with the values here.
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(values);
    // You'll get both the username and password.
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="Username"
          className="form-control"
          id="Username"
          placeholder="Username"
          name="username"
          value={values.username}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control"
          id="Password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

More details here: [Creating a full-stack MERN application using JWT authentication: Part 3](https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-app-jwt-authentication-part-3/).

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a submit button in a form, you should use the `onSubmit` handler on the form element rather than `onClick` on the button. Without it the form gets submitted and hence the page reloads.